# Trouble implementing a generic sort function

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a generic sort method for my homework and this is what I've got:

```
void mySort(int(*condition)(TElement,TElement), DynamicArray *arr)
{
    if (arr == NULL)
        return;
    if (arr->elems == NULL)
        return;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < arr->length - 1; i++)
        for (j = i; j < arr->length; j++)
            if (condition(arr->elems[i], arr->elems[j]) == 0)
            {
                TElement *aux = arr->elems[i];
                arr->elems[i] = arr->elems[j];
                arr->elems[j] = aux;
            }
}
```

My condition struct is defined like this:

```
typedef int(*condition)(Country*, Country*);
```

// I have an array of "countries" and I need to sort them in all kinds of ways

What I'm having trouble is where to write the actual condition methods (Maybe in my Repository module) and how to define it. 
I tried like this:

```
int conditionAsByPop(Country* c1, Country* c2) \\Condition to sort ascending by population
{
    if (c1->population > c2->population)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't know how to actually call it ...

```
void sortAsByPop(CountryRepo* v)
{
    mySort(conditionAsByPop(????), v);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing to `mySort` a pointer to a function as one argument, to use for the comparison. In C, a function name is equivalent to a function pointer, as opposed to variables. Basically, you have to define the comparison function, such as `conditionAsByPop`, and call `mySort` with that function:

```
void sortAsByPop(CountryRepo* v)
{
    mySort(conditionAsByPop, v);
}
```